# Making PHP notice the link ? (Not sure how to explain)

Tags: php, hyperlink, html

Basically I need a basic PHP webpage that does something like this.

1. User enters "www.stackoverflow.com/test#thisIsString"
2. Website prints out thisIsString

I'm unsure how to do anything like this or what this would be called. Any help or just anything that could lead me on the right track is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The anchor is resolved in the browser - it's not even sent to the server so PHP has no way to read it. There are plenty of work-arounds if you can be more specific about what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have enough credits to reply to your post, so I will post an answer, assuming I know what you want to do.

So basically you want to sent data through the URL and handle it.

You can do this: (sending data using GET method)

```
www.mywebsite.com/?c=myContent
```

and on the index page you can write the following code:

```
<?php
  echo $_GET['c'];
?>
```